Verbatim does not produce the expected ASCII character
I have an issue with verbatim content, both with raw verbatim and with fancyvrb package (that I use a lot).
I expect verbatim content to be outputed as exact match, as long as only raw ASCII characters are used.
Consider this MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
'a'
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}

The input is 3 ASCII characters: 27,61,27 (hex).
Now, if I compile this with pdflatex and I copy paste the pdf content into a text editor, and I check the file with:
$ xxd test.pdf

I get these 3 UTF-8 characters:
e2 80 99 - 61 - e2 80 99
This means that the verbatim environments "translates" the ASCII character 27 into the
U+2019 Unicode character.
(check https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2019)
Can this be related to the inputenc / fontenc packages?
What can I do to get the exact 0x27 character in verbatim (and Verbatim/fancyvrb) environnements?

Probably use the upquote package

Ha! Thanks for pointing me on this package, never heard of it but it clearly addresses that issue. Would you consider adding that as answer so I can accept it?

This question is similar to: How can I get straight single quotes in a custom Verbatim command? (The suggested method for geting "straight" quotation marks is to load the upquote package.) If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This this generally solved using the upquote package. Thus there is probably an older answer.
